# Explaining TM notation in Lewis/Papadimitriou

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, notation

I was working on some questions in the book "Elements Of The Theory Of Computation", by Lewis and Papadimitriou, and I need help with one question - question 4.1.8 (chapter 4):

> Give the full details of the turing machines illustrated:
>
> >LL.
>
> [image]

I managed to solve everything but this, and that is because I don't know what the dot is used for. Couldn't find any explanation in the book.
There are two more machines in this question (without dots), but I solved them.

Comment: This is all that was written. Earlier in the book, was explained that L means move one step left. So I understood that this machine moves twice to the left. But then what? I don't know whether this dot is a mistake, a part of the alphabet (which isn't described at all), or some action that needs to be performed but was not discussed earlier.

Comment: Recall that "*if $a\in\Sigma$, then the $a$-writing machine will be denoted simply as $a$*". What if the dot represents just the TM that writes a dot?

Comment: This is what I am asking. I thought that perhaps someone has an answer from the solution manual, or maybe knows what this means in general.